# Why is my map view permanently incremented downward each time it moves?

Tags: java, dictionary, camera

Here is a link to a video I recorded of my issue: https://sendvid.com/rjpi6vnw
You'll notice that initially, I start at tile (0, 0) then after moving my character up and down multiple times, the screen will only go up to (1,0). So I lost a whole row of playable map. I only lose part of the map when my screen adjusts itself. You'll understand what I mean in a moment. I have a class called Player, and in it I have methods called moveRight(), moveLeft(), moveUp(), and moveDown(). I'm excluding all useless classes and methods in order to not waste your time. Here are my moveDown() and moveUp() methods:

```
    public void moveUp(){
        locY1 -= defaultMoveAmount;
        if(viewShouldMoveVertically(locX1, locY1) == true){ //locX1 and locY1 refers to the player's bounds location as set by setBounds()
            Display.uni.moveMapDown(defaultMoveAmount); //Display.uni just means in the Display class
        }
    }
    public void moveDown(){
        locY1 += defaultMoveAmount;
        if(viewShouldMoveVertically(locX1, locY1) == true){
            Display.uni.moveMapUp(defaultMoveAmount); //defaultMoveAmount is the # of pixels the player moves each time the program updates
        }
    }
```

So I have KeyListeners that decide when these methods are called. The viewShouldMoveVertically() method is as follows:

```
    public boolean viewShouldMoveVertically(int X1, int Y1){
        if(Y1 < screenCenterY){ //screenCenterY is the number of vertical pixels on my screen/2
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The moveMapUp() or moveMapDown() method is then called in the Display class:

```
int backgroundX1 = 0;
int backgroundY1 = 0;
public void moveMapUp(int moveAmt){
    backgroundY1 -= moveAmt;
    background.setBounds(backgroundX1, backgroundY1, backgroundX2 , backgroundY2);
}
public void moveMapDown(int moveAmt){
    backgroundY1 += moveAmt;
    background.setBounds(backgroundX1, backgroundY1, backgroundX2 , backgroundY2);
}
```

So if you can't view the video at the link I posted, I'll describe the issue. When my character moves close to the edge of the map, I obviously wouldn't want the camera to show areas off of the map. So the camera stops, but my character may continue walking up to the border of the map. If my character is within 540 pixels of the top of the map, the camera won't move(I'm running on a 1920x1080 display). This is intended. When I move the character more than 540 pixels from the top of the map, the camera will now move with the player since he's in the center of the screen. But the issue is that IF and ONLY IF the camera ends up moving away from the top of the map, then I now lose exactly "defaultMoveAmount" pixels from the viewable area when I return to the top again. I can't seem to figure out how to fix this issue. Now, a little more you may end up wanting to know: I have the same issue moving horizontally as I have moving vertically. It is set up in the same way, so there was no point in making you guys read extra code. When viewing the video at the link, I have to click on the play button at the bottom left, or else it tries to make me add an extension to Chrome or something. The solution to my program's issue may end up being quite simple, but I just can't seem to figure it out. I ended up getting sick of it and decided getting a little help would be better than giving up for now. I am a beginner to programming, as I've only had 1 year of programming experience from an AP Compute Science class. I'm sure you may see a few things that seem dumb, and I welcome any suggestions or comments you may have, but please be aware that I am fairly new to this stuff. Primarily motion. And finally, I did not post a compile-able section of code due to things such as the graphics that are required. While I'm on here, if you have any suggestions or good references for figuring out whether a character is within an area in a large tile-like map, such as a door that can be opened, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. Here is my updated viewShouldMoveVertically() method:

```
public boolean viewShouldMoveVertically(int X1, int Y1){
    if( Y1 <= screenCenterY && previousY1 > screenCenterY ){ //if just touched highest camera point from below
        return true;
    }else if( Y1 >= mapPixelTotalY-screenCenterY && previousY1 < mapPixelTotalY-screenCenterY ){ //if just touched lowest camera point from above
        return true;
    } else if( Y1 <= screenCenterY){ //if just touched highest camera point from above or is just above
        return false;
    } else if( Y1 >= mapPixelTotalY-screenCenterY ){ //If touched lowest camera point from below or is just below
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It turns out that when the player touches the "highest camera point from below" or the "highest camera point from above", different results are required. If touching the highest camera view from below, the camera still needs to move upwards just one more time. But when touching that same point from above, the camera shouldn't move, since the player was coming from an area that the camera wouldn't be vertically moving at.You can see my solution in the code. Also, I added a "previousY1" that records what the last Y1 value was, so that I can tell whether the player came from above or below.